# Seleccionar las voces con speechSynthesis.getVoices() javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un código largo, pero resumiendo en una linea

```js
console.log(speechSynthesis.getVoices());
```

Muestra en Firefox un array de objetos de voces, para otros browser no funciona y dan un array vacío.

Que tengo que hacer para tener voces en otros browsers.

El sandbox de stackoverflow también no funciona, se ve []

Comment: Creo que funciona con una promise, no estoy seguro, pero si es el caso, asegurate de primero hacer un handle para la promise para esperar la correcta respuesta del navegador y ahi si obtener las voces.

Answer (score 1):

Cuándo apenas está cargando la página, generalmente no se ha inicializado el sintetizador de voz y es común que devuelva una lista de voces vacía.

Puedes valerte del evento [`onvoiceschanged`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/voiceschanged_event), que se dispara siempre que cambia la lista de voces disponibles, por ejemplo, cuándo se termina de inicializar el sintetizador.

Te dejo un ejemplo que lanza [`getVoices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices) al inicio, cómo tú lo haces, y generalmente vas a ver solamente `[]` en la consola, y luego lo lanza cuándo se dispara el evento del cambio de voces y, entonces si, imprimirá en la consola la lista de voces disponibles.

Para que puedas diferenciar la salida, he *rodeado* de los mensajes *iniciando* e *inicio terminado* la impresión a consola de inicio (fuera del evento). Lo que veas después del mensaje de *inicio terminado* es lo que se imprime al dispararse el evento:

```js
const synth = window.speechSynthesis;

function showVoiceList() {
  x = synth.getVoices();
  console.log(x);
}


console.log("iniciando");
showVoiceList()
if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
  speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = showVoiceList;
}
console.log("inicio terminado");
```

El sintetizador, por supuesto que funciona dentro del sandbox de StackOverflow, con algunos pequeños ajustes te dejo el ejemplo que está en la documentación misma. Para probarlo haz clic en *Mostrar fragmento de código"*:

```js
const synth = window.speechSynthesis;

const inputForm = document.querySelector("form");
const inputTxt = document.querySelector(".txt");
const voiceSelect = document.querySelector("select");

const pitch = document.querySelector("#pitch");
const pitchValue = document.querySelector(".pitch-value");
const rate = document.querySelector("#rate");
const rateValue = document.querySelector(".rate-value");

let voices = [];

function populateVoiceList() {
  voices = synth.getVoices().sort(function (a, b) {
    const aname = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const bname = b.name.toUpperCase();

    if (aname < bname) {
      return -1;
    } else if (aname == bname) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return +1;
    }
  });
  const selectedIndex =
    voiceSelect.selectedIndex < 0 ? 0 : voiceSelect.selectedIndex;
  voiceSelect.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = `${voices[i].name} (${voices[i].lang})`;

    if (voices[i].default) {
      option.textContent += " -- DEFAULT";
    }

    option.setAttribute("data-lang", voices[i].lang);
    option.setAttribute("data-name", voices[i].name);
    voiceSelect.appendChild(option);
  }
  voiceSelect.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
}

populateVoiceList();

if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
  speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = populateVoiceList;
}

function speak() {
  if (synth.speaking) {
    console.error("speechSynthesis.speaking");
    return;
  }

  if (inputTxt.value !== "") {
    const utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(inputTxt.value);

    utterThis.onend = function (event) {
      console.log("SpeechSynthesisUtterance.onend");
    };

    utterThis.onerror = function (event) {
      console.error("SpeechSynthesisUtterance.onerror");
    };

    const selectedOption =
      voiceSelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-name");

    for (let i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
      if (voices[i].name === selectedOption) {
        utterThis.voice = voices[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    utterThis.pitch = pitch.value;
    utterThis.rate = rate.value;
    synth.speak(utterThis);
  }
}

inputForm.onsubmit = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  speak();

  inputTxt.blur();
};

pitch.onchange = function () {
  pitchValue.textContent = pitch.value;
};

rate.onchange = function () {
  rateValue.textContent = rate.value;
};

voiceSelect.onchange = function () {
  speak();
};
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1, p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.txt, select, form > div {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.txt {
  width: 80%;
}

select {
  width: 83%;
}

form > div {
  width: 81%;
}

.txt, form > div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.rate-value, .pitch-value {
  float: right;
  width: 5%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#rate, #pitch {
  float: right;
  width: 81%;
}

.controls {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.controls button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sintetizador de voz</h1>
<p>
  Ingresa algún texto en el recuadro abajo y presiona enter o el botón "hablar" para 
  escucharlo. Cambia de voz usando el combo box.
</p>
<form>
  <label for="txt">Texto</label>
  <input id="txt" type="text" class="txt" />
  <div>
    <label for="rate">Velocidad</label
    ><input type="range" min="0.5" max="2" value="1" step="0.1" id="rate" />
    <div class="rate-value">1</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="pitch">Tono</label
    ><input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="0.1" id="pitch" />
    <div class="pitch-value">1</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <select></select>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="play" type="submit">Hablar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

En ambos casos, haz clic en el botón "Ejecutar" del *snippet* para ver el código en acción aquí mismo en la respuesta.